# Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate : No certificate with private key found in the specified X.509 certificate content

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I'm facing a strange issue, that I'm unable to fix it with PowerShell and Azure Key Vault. In few words, I'm creating a CSR from KeyVault with `Add-AzKeyVaultCertificate` and a Policy, then I sumit it to an online SSL Certificate Provider. Then, when I get the certificate from provider, I'm trying to merge the request with a simple command ->

```
Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $kv_name -Name $cert_name -CertificateString $cert_response
```

I've this error message after calling this previous command ->

```
Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
Code: BadParameter
Message: No certificate with private key found in the specified X.509 certificate content. Please specify X.509 certificate content with only one certificate containing private key.
```

So, I can understand that my System.Object back from provider doesn't have the correct format. I try to force ToString(), etc.. but no way. And suprising, it's that I just use a temporary file, it's works as epxpected, so the content is good. For example wit this next command, all is ok ->

```
$cert_response | Out-File "$($cert_name).cer"
Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $kv_name -Name $cert_name -FilePath "$($cert_name).cer"
```

On my goal, is to not use temporary file and use variables object directly from provider's response, and use CertificateString arguments for merge request, or maybe CertificateCollection with a X509Certificate2Collection (BTW one of them, just need in my case to not use file intermediate). I was able to create a X509Certificate2 object with `[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::CreateFromPem($cert_response)`, but then Import key vault command say me that I don't have private key (No certificate with private key found in the specified X.509 certificate content. Please specify X.509 certificate content with only one certificate containing private key.). So I guess that this command is only for import full certificate with private key (PKCS12, ...) and not for merge request.

Are there anyone who have experience on this, and have a solution for permit merge request without using temporary file please ?

Thank you so much,
Regards
Alexandre

Comment: Is the string content of the output exactly the same as the content of created file?  Also, consider if the headers of the content need to be removed in order for the cert to be merged.  My suspicion is that there is additional information in the string that is removed when the content is read as a file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. yes, it is. When I write-Host content, it's exactly the same the file that I write, with return carriage too. SO that's why I'm confused about this extra step to write content variable to temp file